# Overcoming same private IP addresses, different subnets

Tags: routing, remote-access, subnet, site-to-site-vpn

I am preparing for migration to VMWare ESXi. Part of this involves P2V a large number of physical servers. Since a lot of our applications depend on the IP addresses to stay the same (i.e. they directly reference the IP addresses, which is bad), we do not want to change IP's when we migrate.

Our physical (current) data center is connected to our site via a L2L VPN. We do not want to take this down. However, we would like to access the new datacenter from certain hosts in our site using remote access VPN.

The question is: will the remote access VPN "override" the L2L VPN in terms of routing traffic?

Answer (score 0):

What VPN client are you using? T
typically if you do not have split tunnels turned on you will not be able to access local LAN resources while connected to a VPN client.